# 連番として名付けたオブジェクトの名称を用いて、複数のCSVファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: r

お世話になっております。R言語についてお伺いさせて頂きたく存じます。
データとして100個のcsvファイルを保有しており、次のような規則性のあるデータ名です。

0001,0002,0003・・0010,0011,0012,・・0099,0100

これらのデータ名を表現するにはfor構文上でformatC関数を用いて作成するところまではわかりました。

次にそうして作成したデータ名を用いてcsvファイルを連番にしたがって読み込み、
次のような名称をもつオブジェクトに格納していきたいと考えています。

data0001,data0002,・・・・,data0100

そのために次のようにコードを書きました。

```
for(i in 1:100){
  i<-formatC(i,width=4,flag="0")
  df<-paste(i, ".csv", sep="")   
  eval(parse(text=paste("data", i, "<-read.csv('", df, "')", sep=""))) 
}
```

参考にしたウェブサイトは下記です。

[Rで複数のcsvファイルを読み込む - Qiita](https://qiita.com/SuRuRa/items/2d7cbb7559ac0002ccf0)

しかし、他の質問スレッドを拝見したり、試行錯誤をしても、うまくいきませんでした。
申し訳ありませんが、このコードのどこにエラーがあるのかをご教示頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: 前回の [R言語でループを用いて順番に要素を取り出し、それぞれ別のオブジェクトに自動で格納していく方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75220/) と同じ方法でも可能です。`for(i in 1:100) assign(sprintf('data%04d', i), read.csv(sprintf('%04d.csv', i)))`

Comment: ご回答頂き、ありがとうございました。不勉強で申し訳ありません。お教え頂いた内容で解決を致しました。ご厚意に感謝申し上げます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「ある場所にあるCSVファイルを全て読みこみたい」との解釈でよろしければ、
ファイル一覧を取得してしまう方が早いと思いましたがいかがでしょうか？

下記の二行だけで済みますよ

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

# data リストに、 0001-0100 の tibble を格納
f <- list.files(path = [保存場所], pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
data <- lapply(f, read_csv)
```

参考までに、リストの操作例も記載します：

```
# リスト操作： 「0010のデータが欲しい」時は、このようにインデックスを指定します
print(data[10])

# リスト操作：「インデックスは、レンジでも指定できます
print(data[10:20])

# リストは、このように縦結合することもできます
alldata <- data %>% bind_rows
```

また read.csv() は非常に古い関数で、遅い上に勝手にfactor化する問題などがありますので、
余程の理由がない限り read_csv() を使った方がよろしいかと思います。（3倍くらい速いです）

Comment: ありがとうございます。このようなやり方もあるとは、存じませんでした。またread.csvの問題についても知らず、お教え頂きまして感謝申し上げます。本サイトに来たばかりの私のような立ち位置ですと、どの内容をどのタイミングで質問するのが公共にとっても有益なのか、判別しづらく感じることもあり恐縮ですが、今後ともどうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: もし参考になりましたら、「回答を承認」を押して頂けますと、他の方の参考になります。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答の承認を行いました。今回、ご回答頂いた皆様に改めて御礼申し上げます。大変参考になりました。